# Printing a message if a char has more than one symbol(using char, not String)

Tags: java

Basically I need to write this message:
`System.out.println("Invalid grade - must enter exactly one letter");`

And I don't know how to write an (if,for,while loop) which will find if **letterGrade** is bigger than one character, it has to be only one character if > 1 character it should follow this message.

And problem is that I know how to do it with `string.length()` but this is char and it doesn't work.
I tried this:

```
        while(String.valueOf(letterGrade).length() > 1)
                       {
                          System.out.println("Invalid grade - must enter exactly one letter");
                          System.out.print("Enter grade (one character): ");
                          letterGrade = in.next().charAt(0);
                       }
```

But it doesn't print me message that I want, is there some method that finds char greater than one character? Can `charAt()` help me ?

Comment: I would propose to use regular expression since you might want to only allow letters a-f/A-F

Expression to use would be "[a-fA-F]".

Comment: agreed with Phiwa and can you structure your question in readable format

Comment: Phiwa, what is the best way to write that code if I may ask ? I don't know how to unite it with char exactly.

Comment: I posted an example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose to use regular expression since you might want to only allow letters a-f/A-F.
The expression to use would be

```
[a-fA-F]
```

The Java code used to check this would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Type");

        Scanner reader = null;

        try {

            // Read from System.in
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Only work with first character
            char c = reader.findInLine(".").charAt(0);

            // ""+c creates a string since RegEx only works on strings
            String testString = ""+c;

            // Test string
            if(!(""+c).matches("[a-fA-F]")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                return;
            }

            // c has a valid grade
            System.out.println("Valid input");      
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            if(reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }   
}
```

Test results:

```
a   >  Valid input
z   >  Invalid input
az  >  Valid input
za  >  Invalid input
```

Comment: I did like this: char letterGrade = in.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
String testString = "" + letterGrade;
            if(!testString.matches("[a-fA-F]"))
            {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            return;
            }    And I get nullPointer exception error

Comment: When do you get that and in which line?

Comment: in this: char letterGrade = in.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
Enter grade (one character): Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ComputeGpa.main(ComputeGpa.java:16)

Comment: I just updated the code above with a full class example and it perfectly works for me

Answer (score 0):

You may use `System.in.read();` if you want to read only one charactor.

Answer (score 0):

So you should probably be a little more clear with your question and not in a paragraph form with the entire block of code including variable declaration and user inputlines.
In java, a char can only be one character (i am sure you know this) and so having multiple would mean that it is a string.

Assuming that you are working with letterGrade as an input from the user using Scanner, the way to check if the input is one character or not and do something in response will be

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
if(input.length==1)
{sysout("There is only 1 character in the input");
char value = input.indexOf(0);
}else
{sysout("Invalid grade");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response but it has to be char this input. char LetterGrade = scanner.next().charAt(0);

Comment: try char letterGrade = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);

Comment: or  char letterGrade = (char) System.in.read();    Although if you do it this way you need to trycatch a IOException